# Analogue of UiApp.createApplication()?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I need help, try to use `HtmlService.createHtmlOutput()` but it doesn't work...
Sorry, only begin to learn

```
function doGet() {
           var data = Charts.newDataTable()
               .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Month")
               .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "In Store")
               .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Online")
               .addRow(["January", 10, 1])
               .addRow(["February", 12, 1])
               .addRow(["March", 20, 2])
               .addRow(["April", 25, 3])
               .addRow(["May", 30, 4])
               .build();

           var chart = Charts.newAreaChart()
               .setDataTable(data)
               .setStacked()
               .setRange(0, 40)
               .setTitle("Sales per Month")
               .build();

           /*var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("My Chart");
           uiApp.add(chart);*/

           var uiApp = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput();
           uiApp.setContent(chart);

           return uiApp;
         }
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain better what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: you are mixing uiApp with htmlService. use one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copied this code from the Google Charts overview page. There are a lot of ways to use the chart function however.

If you're just trying to learn about it I recommend starting with learning the HTML associated with the charts service. Here is the developers [Quick Start Guide](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) which should walk you through how to create the appropriate html content. You can then use the HTMLService to display the content.